# 42042 Crawler Crane: conversion to remote control

Tags: technic, building, set-modification

After many years of "Lego drought", I have decided to reinvest in some. Amongst a lot I have purchased is a Crawler Crane, half built, with all the parts to complete the build.

However, instead of building as the instructions, has anyone here actually converted this to remote control, so you don't have to keep reaching for the back of the crane to operate the shift levers?

I've seen a few videos on YouTube, but they don't explain the how to make the modifications.

Comment: Welcome back to LEGO and to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 8):

There's a nice looking [mod on Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/MOC-4078/Catweazel/42042-rc/) that includes full building instructions.

[image: 42042 mod instruction step]

This includes the following PF components:

- 2 L-Motors - drive
- 1 M-Motor - tilt cab
- 1 M-Motor - boom elevation
- 1 M-Motor - rotate
- 1 M-Motor - winch
- 3 IR Receiver
- 3 IR Remote Control
- 1 Battery Box